# Pull down to reload like Gmail with AngularJS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, swipe

I should to do a "pull down to reload" like Gmail.

I've already created the div with the "reload" icon, but I don't find a solution.. I've searched in internet, but I doesn't find what I need.

I've tried with $swipe function (angularJS) but works only in horizontal. I need a script like $swipe function, but that works only when I'm at the top of the page, only for a swipe down and the normale scroll must work.

[image: Pull down to reload]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this library, it implements swiping any direction, angularjs 1.3+

https://github.com/marmorkuchen-net/angular-swipe

Comment: This library have the "move" event that the $swipe has?

Comment: I'm not sure, it's described as "Small extension of the existing angular $swipe service", I'd assume any existing $swipe events still exist.  I do see references to the 'move' event in their source.

Comment: Thanks, but it disable the scroll.. Tomorrow I will try with Swipe jQuery